# Convert for loop by using lambda(C#3.0)

Tags: c#-3.0

How to convert the below code

```
double sumxy = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < x.Count; i++)
{sumxy = sumxy + (x[i] * y[i]);}
```

by using lambda

I am using C#3.0. x and y are list of double numbers

Thanks

Comment: Any why would you want to use a lambda here?

Comment: @Lucero because it is so cool! everyone are speaking about lambda! it might be the thing that will fix everything!!! /sarcasm

Comment: @Andrey, riiiiight... I may be old-fashioned, but I think that LINQ and related things are being overused a lot. Not to speak of the hidden caveats in it, such as the deferred execution with most (but not all) LINQ operations etc., which I feel are difficult to grasp for many fellow developers.... *For they know not what they do*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're using .NET 4, you could use the [`Zip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx) operator:

```
double sumxy = x.Zip(y, (a, b) => a * b).Sum();
```

Or in .NET 3.5:

```
double sumxy = x.Select((value, index) => value * y[index]).Sum();
```

Answer (score 3):

There isn't really any point, but if you want to:

```
Enumerable.Range(0, x.Count).Select(i => x[i] * y[i]).Sum();
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this...

```
var sumy = Enumerable.Range(0, x.Count).Aggregate((result, i) => result + (x[i]*y[i]);
```